# remove stripe pattern in image taken by microscope

Tags: opencv, image-processing, noise-reduction

This picture is taken by a microscope.

[image: original image]

I want to remove the stripes on it. I have tried `DFT` but it seems these stripes isn't sharp on spectrum domain.

[image: spectrum domain]

Any advice?

Comment: Right,just want to get rid of the stripes.

Comment: I misunderstood.I mean I want to get rid of the stripes,and keep the rest.

Comment: Yes,that is my purpose.

Comment: No need to recover that,erase those lines would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer 1: Remove stripe directly from FFT

When I compute the FFT and we got the following image where we can see the stripe signature (I surrounded it in black).

[image: FFT]

If I remove it by hand I got that:

[image: without strip]

We can do better be removing only frequency arroud each maximum in cardinal sine.

## Answer 2: Segment stripe

process : FFT -> select stripe frequency -> iFFT -> Threshold 
The resulting mask contain your stripe. You can substract them from origin image, fill them etc ... 
FFT with only stripe :

[image: FFT with only stripe]

The resulting mask :

[image: The mask]

## Answer 3: Change Capture process

It seem this stripe come from interference between your microscope slide and your cover slip. You can probably remove it by changing you process.

Comment: I wonder how to have a interactive environment like this?Thank you.

Comment: Actually it's something on the surface of the material.Anyway,Thanks.

Comment: I have downloaded the program and done the FFT part.Now I am confusing with the part of FFT with only stripes.How can I select only the stripe frequency?And I don't understand the threshold part.Sorry if that sounds foolish,new to the CV domain.

Comment: @guojia 1) process to select only stripe frequency on ImageJ :  right clic on oval selection -> select Elliptical selection -> select stripe -> Image/Selection/Make Inverse -> Edit/Fill -> Process/FTT/Inverse FFT
2) process for threshold : Edit/Adjust/Threshold

Comment: Thank you,absolutely helpful.The above order of the Image and Edit should reverse.

Comment: By the way,can this software fill the original image with the extracted stripe by the color of the background?

Comment: To apply obtained mask to original image, you could use Process/Image calculator and select OR operation. If you want to make an automatic process for lots of images, I will advice you to either switch to opencv in Python or try Macro in ImageJ (It's coded in Java)

Comment: I just found using this methods will not remove the edge of the stripes,strange.It seems the edges is not the same frequency of the stripes.Should I use some methods to "sharp" the stripe,so the stripe will be the same color as a whole?

Comment: you can add a small dilation on your mask, it will increase strip width.

Comment: How can I add a small dilation on the mask since it is generated from spectral domain?

Comment: sorry miss spelling, you can apply a dilatation on your mask

Comment: I got it,but how can I control the width of the lines?Confused.

Comment: dilatation use a kernel to increase shape width, with a kernel of width 2 it will enlarge your shape of 1px on each side

Comment: That's a lot help! Hope not too disturbing.Can you give a hint of how to select stripes signature in spectral domain.Last question.

Comment: An automatic method ? hough transform in the original image will detect line and give you their orientation, with this orientation you know where are their signature in spectrum domain.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Because you only have 3 dominant colors in the image and the stripes color is different from the other objects color, you will probably get the best result by using the objects color and doing a segmentation based on it, for instance using kmeans with k=3 then replace all the pixels that belongs to the darkest cluster with the mean value of the lightest cluster.

Solution 2:

Use hough lines to detect lines in the image,
Find the lightest color in the image,
Draw the lines detected with the lightest color.

Both solutions can be implemented in OpenCV.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you!Both methods are very enlightening.

Comment: It turns out that kmeans using 3 colors would leave the edges of stripes undetected.Because the color of the edge is more lighter than inside.What should I do?

Comment: 1. threshold the image: set every pixel inside one of the 2 foreground cluster as white and every pixel of the bg as black 2. Use the image as a mask for the original image 3. Run Kmeans again with k=3  4.remove the pixels in the smallest cluster (also the darkest cluster).

Comment: The edge of the stripe is labeled same with the part I want to keep,not the background.So I suppose I need some other methods? I'm thinking using edge detection first,than fill every pixel with average color of the region.Than kmeans should tell the difference between the stripe and the character I want to keep.

Comment: The edge is labeled the same when *all* of the image is being clustered,but if you will cluster the image again without the darkest pixels(as i wrote) suddenly the edge pixels will become the darkest and will merge to their own cluster. Just try what i wrote, it should work and if not upload the code

Comment: The step2,by mask you mean AND or what?And why removing the darkest pixels is step4,since you said remove darkest pixels before kmeans.I'm confused.

Comment: In the first step you create a mask (all bg pixels are 0 and fg are 255) then you should use it as mask : origImg.copyTo(newImage, mask) will copy only non zero pixels to newImage , that is all the edges that were left and the main objects without the pixels that were allready been removed on the first kmeans, now run kmeans on newImage and you will get one cluster for the edges pixels (darkest pixels) one for the main objects and one for background,then remove all the pixels in the darkest cluster (the edges pixels).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helps above!After some experiment I have implement a method that I assume works well.

Use Fourier first,than apply a filter called tophat to the magnitude image.Than the bright dots will be selected.After remove it from frequency domain, than inverse fft,the stripes will be removed.Then the image need to be filtered to extract the foreground alone.I use Gaussian filter,it works but not perfect.It seems some structure extraction filter exist,such as Relative Total Variation,I'm not sure,if someone have a better idea please tell me.
The image is like this[After ifft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btVPh.jpg)

Again thanks @Erwan and  @Dr.Haimovitz for all the help.